# What values do I specify for clientid and secret for `OpenID Connect - Get a token`?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, claims-based-identity, openid-connect

I would like to use the REST API to retrieve the IAM token which you can retrieve using the `bx iam oauth-tokens' command:

```
$ bx login --apikey @myapikey.json
$ bx iam oauth-tokens
IAM token:  Bearer ****
UAA token:  Bearer ****
```

By setting `BLUEMIX_TRACE=true`, I can see that there is a call to `https://iam.ng.bluemix.net/oidc/token`.

I've found the [docs for the token service](https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/713-token-service-api?&language=node&env_id=ibm%3Ayp%3Aeu-gb#openid-connect-get-a-token) provide the following information:

> **Authorization** 
>   Authorization Token used for the request. The supported
>   token type is a basic auth token containing a clientid and secret. If
>   the token is omitted, a default client configuration will be used
>   which can only interact with Api Keys.'

```
var options = {
  "method": "POST",
  "hostname": "localhost",
  "port": "443",
  "path": "//oidc/token",
  "headers": {
    "authorization": "string",
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  }
};
```

What should I be setting for `clientid` and `secret`?  Do I need to obtain these values from another API call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way is to omit the authorization header. So this call should work (please note that I am using the global endpoint `iam.bluemix.net` for best availability, and also the new context path `/identity/token`):

`curl -d "grant_type=urn:ibm:params:oauth:grant-type:apikey&apikey=<your API key>" https://iam.bluemix.net/identity/token`